# Why Bootstrap's Carousel left arrow throws errors while the right one works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have created this page http://www.virtuemax.com/projects/urtotal/index.html

Its a static page and built entirely on bootstrap's framework. The carousel works fine but when you click the left arrow to navigate the carousel to the left it throws errors. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is not written properly

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<img id="floral" src="img/floralOrange.png" alt="">

<div class="item active">
    <img alt="Slide 1" src="img/slide1.jpg">
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img alt="" src="img/slide2.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

The first image should be wrapped inside `<div class="item"></div>` like the other.
Also you are including 2 jquery plugin at a time. Remove one to avoid unwanted conflict

Comment: It was due to putting that image inside the div with class name=carousel-inner. I needed that image for design's sake. Now that I have removed that image out of that div, it all works fine.