# Slick Carousel Left Arrow hidden

Tags: html, css, carousel, css-shapes

I use slick carousel on a web site. The right arrow is well displayed.

My problem is that the left arrow is hidden.

You can see the problem online at : [carryall.fr](http://www.carryall.fr)

I checked this question : [Why Bootstrap's Carousel left arrow throws errors while the right one works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114410/why-bootstraps-carousel-left-arrow-throws-errors-while-the-right-one-works-fine)  but it does not seem to be the same issue.

Here is my html structure :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="ca_slider">
        <div><a href='{root_url}' title='{sitename}'><img src='{uploads_url}/images/slideshow02.jpg'  alt='{sitename}' /></a></div>
        <div><a href='{root_url}' title='{sitename}'><img src='{uploads_url}/images/slideshow03.jpg'  alt='{sitename}' /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your Z-index. It's not set high enough on the button, so it is behind the picture.

In your CSS file, find where the styles are for the next and prev buttons, and add a Z-index.

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    ....     
    z-index:999;
}
```

The reason the right arrow is visible, but the left one is hidden, is because of the order of your html lines.

It goes: Left Button, Picture, Right Button

So that is how it is layered on the screen, which causes the picture to cover the left button. Z-Index lets you fix that by saying the buttons should appear above the other layers on the Z-axis.

---

**Update:**

In reference to your second question from the comments, where you cannot select the text in the slides:

The issue is the CSS3 rule to disable text selection. user-Select, -moz-user-select, -ms-user-select, or -webkit-user-select. Based on the browser.

```
.slick-slider {
   ....       
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
   ....
}
```

You need to remove those lines for your CSS file.